# When ArgumentNullException is missing Parameter Name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In my application a few times `ArgumentNullException` is thrown, but without any Parameter Name supplied. This has happened only in production (exception is thrown in a script service, called by javascript).
I tried to reproduce this kind of error in the code snippet pointed by the StackTrace, but every `ArgumentNullException` I was able to reproduce included some Parameter Name in its message.

So, my question is does anyone know when `ArgumentNullException` is thrown without Parameter Name supplied? or What method could eventually trigger this very exception?

The script service is about getting some information from Application cache:

```
private Dictionary<int, MyType> CachedDictionary
{
    get
    {
        //return the Item from the application cache
        return GetItem() as Dictionary<int, MyType>;
    }
    set
    {
        //adds the Item to the application cache 
        //with sliding expiration of X minutes
        AddItem(value);
    }
}

public List<MyType> Get(List<int> idsToRead)
{
    List<int> idsNotCached = idsToRead.Except<int>(CachedDictionary.Keys.ToList<int>()).ToList<int>();
    if (idsNotCached.Count > 0)
    {
        //Exception stack trace points to next line:
        MyTypeCollection DBitems = BusinessLayer.StaticLoadFromDB(idsNotCached); 
        lock (CachedDictionary)
        {
            foreach (MyType item in DBitems)
                if (!CachedDictionary.ContainsKey(item.ID))
                    CachedDictionary.Add(item.ID, item);
        }
    }
    return CachedDictionary.Where(p => idsToRead.Contains(p.Key)).Select(p => p.Value).ToList<MyType>();
}


public static MyTypeCollection StaticLoadFromDB(List<int> ids)
{
    try
    {
        //load from db...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return HandleException<MyType>(e);
        //returns MyTypeCollection with HasError set to TRUE and defined ErrorMessage
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in a method you wrote? If it is then it shouldn't matter that the parameter name isn't supplied, you should just error handle accordingly

Comment: There's a constructor that takes [zero arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdfe72hy.aspx). I'd expect the parameter name to be null if that constructor were used.

Comment: Damien, no such constructors are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys, thank you very much for your attention.
As Kami suggested, i added some additional logging and fortunately the exception was reproduced and everything is clear now.
It appears that after this line:

```
List<int> idsNotCached = idsToRead.Except<int>(CachedDictionary.Keys.ToList<int>()).ToList<int>();
```

(see provided code example above) CachedDictionary has expired and on line:

```
lock (CachedDictionary)
```

an ArgumentNullException is thrown without parameter name supplied. Apparently I missed to test this lock.
With some additional lines of code the issue is resolved:

```
public List<MyType> Get(List<int> idsToRead)
{
    Dictionary<int, MyType> localCachedDictionary = CachedDictionary;
    if (localCachedDictionary == null)
        localCachedDictionary = new Dictionar<int, MyType>();
    List<int> idsNotCached = idsToRead.Except<int>(localCachedDictionary.Keys.ToList<int>()).ToList<int>();
    if (idsNotCached.Count > 0)
    {
        //Exception stack trace points to next line:
        MyTypeCollection DBitems = BusinessLayer.StaticLoadFromDB(idsNotCached); 
        lock (localCachedDictionary)
        {
            foreach (MyType item in DBitems)
                if (!localCachedDictionary.ContainsKey(item.ID))
                    localCachedDictionary.Add(item.ID, item);
        }
    }
    if (CachedDictionary == null)
        CachedDictionary = localCachedDictionary;
    return localCachedDictionary.Where(p => idsToRead.Contains(p.Key)).Select(p => p.Value).ToList<MyType>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without code it is difficult to identify the possible causes.  You can try the following general guideline to try and identify the problem.

The exception `ArgumentNullException` is usually triggered when an argument to a method is not supplied.  The constructor to `ArgumentNullException` does not require a parameter name to supplied.  Some methods only take one parameter and as such, there is no need to supply the name of the parameter which is null.

The exception can be triggered at any point in code by simply

```
throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

To help identify the location and there by the cause of the issue, you need to look at the stack trace and then look at the parameters being supplied.  Try to identify what the process was trying to do at the time, and thereby the possible parameter values.

Alternatively, you can try adding a try catch that logs possible values sent to the method when it is invoked.  For example,

```
try
{
    FunctionThatThrowsArgumentNullException(myParameter);
} catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
{
    Log.WriteLine("Argument Null Exception Raised", ane);
    Log.WriteLine("Parameters supplied : {0}", myParameter);
    throw; // Pass the exception on, as we are only logging
}
```

Comment: There is exception logging, but some additional logging is a good suggestion. +1

Comment: As you are having trouble identifying the cause, and debug is not an option in production, logging is the only effective solution to try and identify what is going on.

Comment: @Vladislav Thanks for the code.  Have you tried checking the `HandleException<myType>()` code?  If there is an exception in getting the data, this method would be called.  If there is an exception in this method - does it get handled?

Comment: I just looked at that possibility, but all logic in HandleException is custom and no such exception is likely to be thrown. Besides if the exception was in HandleException I guess that the StackTrace would lead me there, not to the line I have pointed above. Thanks for your efforts, Kami!

Comment: did you find my answer useful for you?

Answer (score 2):

ArgumentNullException is public, and anyone can throw this exception. It may be that your colleague, or a 3rd party library you use throws it.

You have to answer your own question, by looking at stack trace in the exception. This will tell you where the exception is thrown at, and all methods which precede it.

Take as an example this code:
[image]

By inspecting the exception, you can see where the error comes from. At top of stack trace is method which thrown the exception, and then chain of method calls that lead to it.
[image]

Comment: Yes, of course, i have investigated the StackTrace, but it is actually very very misleading, because it points to a custom static method with one parameter, but even if that parameter is NULL - no exception is thrown (although for it to be null is really impossible). There is no 3rd party library that could throw this, neither none of my colleagues could do it in production. I will try to supply some code snippet.

Comment: Ok. I've never heard of such things happening, so it must be a problem in debugging setup or something that you're missing. It's possible that you're using debug symbols which don't match the running application. Check in debug settings whether it's allowed that source and running assembly don't match.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you are not using any 3rd party library, the exception might be thrown from within your own codebase. As Kami explained it, the code that raises this exception can be identified as:

```
throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

Why don't you search your codebase for this line? If you are lucky, you would find the place where this exception is raised without passing the parameter name!